# Binary Search Tree Remove method not working

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

```
public class BSTNode <E extends Comparable<E>> {

private E value;
private BSTNode<E> left;
public BSTNode<E> right;
....


public BSTNode<E>remove(E item) {
    if(item.equals(this.value)){

        return replacementSubtreeFromChildren(this.left, this.right);

    }  
    if (item.compareTo(this.value)<0){
     this.left = this.left.remove(item);
    }
    else{this.right = this.right.remove(item);
    }
    return this;
}

private BSTNode<E> replacementSubtreeFromChildren(BSTNode<E> left,       BSTNode<E> right) {
    if(left==null && right==null){      
        return null;
    }
    else if(left!=null && right==null){    
        return this.left;
    }
    else if(left==null && right!=null){        
        return this.right;       
    }
    else{
     E getleft=this.right.getLeftmostNode().getValue();
     this.value = getleft;
     this.right = right.remove(getleft);


    }
    return this;
}

/**
 *  Returns the leftmost node in the subtree formed by the receiver. 
 *  
 *  COMPLETION
 *  
 *  HINT: The code is very simple. Just keep descending left branches, 
 *  until it is no longer possible. 
 * 
 * @returns a reference to the leftmost node, starting from the receiver.    
 *                                          
 */
private BSTNode<E> getLeftmostNode() {
   if (this.left == null) {
    return this;
   }
   else{
       return this.left.getLeftmostNode();
  }
```

For some reason this method will not remove from the tree.
Can anyone help me find why this it is doing this?

I have tested it and all the methods are being accessed, I suspect I have the pointer somewhere incorrectly however cannot find where.

Comment: Have you done any debugging in your IDE?  https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: dont you think when you have found the node to be deleted , you have actually done `return replacementSubtreeFromChildren(this.left, this.right);` , but you should have really used that replacement node and swapped the 2 nodes and deleted the node, I think that is the problem

Comment: Vihar could you be a little more clear sorry

Comment: Your remove() is expected to do what? remove a node or remove complete tree underneath!

Answer (score 0):

inst this for comp103 Assignment 6 at Victoria university for this trimester